# Python - copy full path to a destination folder and keep the path structure

Tags: python

The source structure is like:

```
Z:\Archived\2018\2018_01_01\BOM_Archived\A.nc.gz
...........................\BOM_Archived\B.nc.gz
...........................\BOM_Archived\C.nc.gz
...........................\other files and folders

Z:\Archived\2018\2018_01_02\BOM_Archived\A.nc.gz
...........................\BOM_Archived\B.nc.gz
...........................\BOM_Archived\C.nc.gz
...........................\other files and folders

Z:\Archived\2018\2018_01_03\BOM_Archived\A.nc.gz
...........................\BOM_Archived\B.nc.gz
...........................\BOM_Archived\C.nc.gz
...........................\other files and folders

...
...
...

Z:\Archived\2018\2018_12_31\BOM_Archived\A.nc.gz
...........................\BOM_Archived\B.nc.gz
...........................\BOM_Archived\C.nc.gz
...........................\other files and folders
```

I need to copy the entire BOM_Archive folder only and its contained A.nc.gz, B.nc.gz and C.nc.gz files for each date to:

```
V:\Historical_BOM_Raw\
```

and keep the path structure. The "\other files and folders" should not be copied.

```
V:\Historical_BOM_Raw\2018\2018_01_01\BOM_Archived\A.nc.gz
..................................................\B.nc.gz
..................................................\C.nc.gz

V:\Historical_BOM_Raw\2018\2018_01_02\BOM_Archived\A.nc.gz
..................................................\B.nc.gz
..................................................\C.nc.gz

...
...

V:\Historical_BOM_Raw\2018\2018_12_31\BOM_Archived\A.nc.gz
..................................................\B.nc.gz
..................................................\C.nc.gz
```

I am thinking creating a date folder each time and copy the files from the source folder but should it be a more efficient way?

Comment: Did you have a look at [dirsync](https://pypi.org/project/dirsync/)? Maybe that is helpful for your task.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean by ´and keep the path pattern. ..................................................\B.nc.gz`. Can you add the code you have?

Comment: Thanks@RightmireM. I meant each date folder has A.nc.gz, B.nc.gz and C.nc.gz.

Comment: Thanks@MrFuppes. I would prefer using the Python native modules.

Comment: Ok, if it should come with python, maybe the `pathlib` module is useful. Other than that, go for `os` and `shutil`.